# PHP: how to solve this array of child data model calling view's method

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am trying to write code based on MVC pattern. Job is to create task & its child task from some input and then generate hierarchy tree/array of parent child tasks. But I face a problem when i try to generate some html based views on that task array. I notice that the model object needs to access the view's methods!

> Note: Please ignore any syntax error, it is just to give a problem
>   idea

**Model Class**

```
class TaskModel{
 private $data;
 public TaskModel taskChilds[] = array();
}
```

**View Class**

```
class TaskView{
    private $model;

    public function __construct($model) {
         $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function showTaskHtml($data) {
        // NOT possible because each $data belongs to its corresponding $model
        return "<div>$this->$data</div>";
    }

    public function showChild() {
        foreach($this->$taskModel->taskChilds as  $child ){
            // NOT possible $child is model & the function belongs to view
            echo $child->showTaskHtml($data); 
        }   
    }
}
```

Please help me. Give me some code guide line. I am new at MVC

Comment: In MVC "model" is not an object, but a layer. And your views should be communicating with that layer via the services.

Comment: Thanks @tereško .I think i got many valuable comments from you before on my earlier post.But i thing if i get some more specific code solution suggestion.Then as a novice that could really help me to understand the layer concept.

Comment: I think what @tereško means is that you should have 1 view for each task "controller". TaskViewTypeA, TaskViewTypeB and from your controller render the correct ViewType having in mind the type.